# JavaScript ES2022 private static methods でChromeとSafariの挙動違い

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

以下のJavaScriptコードでSafariとChrome共に動作しますが結果が異なります。
なぜそうなるのか理由が知りたいです。
どうぞご教授ください。

```
<script>
class Bar {
    'use strict';
    baz() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve();
        }).then(() => {
            return [2];
        });
    }
}
new class {
    'use strict';
    #foo = 1;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.#foo); // 1
        (new Bar()).baz()
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);   // [2]
                console.log(this.#foo); // 1
                [this.#foo] = res;
                console.log(this.#foo); //*** Chromeは2、Safariは1 ***
            });
    }
}
</script>
```

なお、#foo の宣言を private static methods にしないで foo にすれば、最後の結果は共に 2 になります。

実行結果が異なるのにChromeもSafariもエラーが出ません。

Chrome 97.0.4692.99
Safari 15.3 (17612.4.9.1.5)
macOS Monterey Ver. 12.2
MacBook Air (M1,2020)

追伸：
以下でも再現することを確認しました。バグなんでしょうか。

```
<script>
new class {
    #foo = 1;
    constructor() {
        [this.#foo] = [2];
        console.log(this.#foo); //*** Chrome: 2, Safari: 1 ***
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari Technology Preview 139 では 2 になりますので、Safari のバグだったのでしょう。分割代入が動かないみたいですね。

Firefox でも2です。